# Entity Framework Included table Null

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using db first and have a particular association that always returns null, using:

```
    var results = _ABPRepository.Query(x => x.ABPArrangementId == arrangementId)
                    .Include(x => x.tb_ARRArrangement)
                    .Include(x => x.tb_ARRArrangement.Supplier)
                    .Include(x => x.tb_ARRArrangement.Supplier.tb_SCNSicCodesNew)
                    .Include(x => x.tb_BBRBatteryBackBrands)
                    .Include(x => x.tb_ARRArrangement.Supplier.Country)
                    .Include(x => x.tb_ARRArrangement.Supplier.InvoiceCountry)
                    .Include(x => x.Country)
                    .Select().FirstOrDefault();
```

The below is always null:

```
x.tb_ARRArrangement.Supplier.tb_SCNSicCodesNew
```

I've verified that the SQL is correct (briefly below):

```
SELECT 
    /* ... */
    [Project1].[SCN_SIC_Code] AS [SCN_SIC_Code], 
    [Project1].[SCN_SIC_Description] AS [SCN_SIC_Description]
    /* ... */
    FROM ( SELECT 
        /* ... */
        [Extent4].[SCN_SIC_Code] AS [SCN_SIC_Code], 
        [Extent4].[SCN_SIC_Description] AS [SCN_SIC_Description],
        /* ... */
        CASE WHEN ([Extent8].[BBRIDNumber] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
        FROM        [dbo].[tb_ABPArrangementBatteryBackProducer] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[tb_ARRArrangement] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ABPArrangementId] = [Extent2].[ARRIDNumber]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tb_SUPSupplier] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[ARRSupplierId] = [Extent3].[SUPKey]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT 
                                [tb_SCNSicCodesNew].[SCN_SIC_Code] AS [SCN_SIC_Code], 
                                [tb_SCNSicCodesNew].[SCN_SIC_Description] AS [SCN_SIC_Description]
                         FROM [dbo].[tb_SCNSicCodesNew] AS [tb_SCNSicCodesNew]) AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[SUPEaHwrSicCode2007] = [Extent4].[SCN_SIC_Code]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tb_COUCountry] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent3].[SUPCountry] = [Extent5].[COUIDNumber]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tb_COUCountry] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent3].[SUPInvoiceCountry] = [Extent6].[COUIDNumber]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[tb_COUCountry] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent1].[ABPCorrespondanceCountry] = [Extent7].[COUIDNumber]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[tb_BBRBatteryBackBrands] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent1].[ABPArrangementId] = [Extent8].[BBRABPIDNumber]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ABPArrangementId] = 123456
    )  AS [Project1]
```

The returned recordset contains the data I expect, but it fails to map to the 
`results.tb_ARRArrangement.Supplier.tb_SCNSicCodesNew` property.

All other includes work as expected.

I've tried:

- Reading about where includes may not work (grouping etc) but they
  don't seem to apply to my scenario as the include is not ignored,
  more that the mapping seems to fail.
- Removing the association and tables from the EDMX and re-adding
- Renaming and re-making the association and navigation properties
- Cleaning and re-building

There isn't a foreign key in the database between the tables, but there aren't on some of the others either and I've had no issues.

Any pointers on things to check?

Comment: How is [ABPArrangementId] defined in your schema  int or varchar ?

Comment: @DaniDev it's an int

Comment: Gottcha! It did seem that way based how the linq engine parsed it. Just wanted to make sure. I don't have a answer, unfortunately.

Comment: are you sure there are matching entries in the database? and are all relationships on the way one-to-many or one-to-one?

Comment: Yes, the generated sql returns the expected data when I run it in ssms. It just fails to map. The relationship is one tb_scnsiccodenew to one supplier, and many suppliers to one tb_scnsiccodenew

Comment: Is your Generated SQL (cant see the whole  query) actually selecting that field tb_SCNSicCodesNew in SSMS if so, what is it's dbType and what value is it showing?

Comment: @danidev, yes, both fields from the table are varchars and I see them in ssms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue in Entity Framework with joining fixed length strings to variable length, as explained here: https://romiller.com/2014/10/20/ef6-1workaround-trailing-blanks-issue-in-string-joins/

> The issue is that SQL Server ignores trailing spaces when comparing
>   strings but the .NET string functions (which EF uses) does not. On SQL
>   Server “ABCD” and “ABCD    “ are considered equal, but in .NET (and
>   EF) they are not.

This resulted in the correct data being selected but not mapped. The code from the above link fixes the issue by adding an interceptor to trim strings:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception;
using System.Linq;

namespace DataRepository
{
    public class StringTrimmerInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
    {
        public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
        {
            if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace == DataSpace.SSpace)
            {
                var queryCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbQueryCommandTree;
                if (queryCommand != null)
                {
                    var newQuery = queryCommand.Query.Accept(new StringTrimmerQueryVisitor());
                    interceptionContext.Result = new DbQueryCommandTree(
                        queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                        queryCommand.DataSpace,
                        newQuery);
                }
            }
        }

        private class StringTrimmerQueryVisitor : DefaultExpressionVisitor
        {
            private static readonly string[] _typesToTrim = { "nvarchar", "varchar", "char", "nchar" };

        public override DbExpression Visit(DbNewInstanceExpression expression)
        {
            var arguments = expression.Arguments.Select(a =>
            {
                var propertyArg = a as DbPropertyExpression;
                if (propertyArg != null && _typesToTrim.Contains(propertyArg.Property.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name))
                    {
                    return EdmFunctions.Trim(a);
                }

                return a;
            });

            return DbExpressionBuilder.New(expression.ResultType, arguments);
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is then initialized by placing the below in the same project as the context:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace FixedLengthDemo
{
    public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public MyConfiguration()
        {
            AddInterceptor(new StringTrimmerInterceptor());
        }
    }
}
```